# How do I scale a section of the model proportionally within sculpt mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms, sculpt-mode

I'm new to Blender and one of the things I'm trying to do is to resize a section of the nose proportionally without affecting its shape.

[image]

The scale tool appears most appropriate for this type of application although at this point I'm not experienced, or knowledgeable enough, to understand how to use it properly.

Comment: I think for something like that you are better off changing to edit mode and scaling it with proportional editing. Then smoothing it out in sculpt mode